# Error while npm install -g cordova

Tags: cordova

I've got an error during cordova installation, this is the console output:

```
C:\Users\Keshao>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2

npm ERR! Invalid protocol: null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Keshao\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The same error I faced. For that I get admin rights for my PC and restarted and followed the below steps. Kindly check in future use..

Answer (score 0):

```
npm_node_cordova_install_error_WARN
===================================

While installing cordova CLI in windows system : Error 

Exect Error: ****npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 - Unable to install cordova on Windows 7****

Do the following steps: 

C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\npm THEN

P:\nodejs\ and one more is tools.jar file not found in c:\prom files\jre_vesion.
Copy tools.jar from c:\prom files\jdk_version and paste. 

**** Kindly make sure the  path is mapping with current user(C:\user\yourname\) 

**** Check Environment variables for JAVA,ant,Android SDK p-tools,tools.
```